# Beautiful Soup python .get full information from html

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, telegram

I am trying to get the number of views of my post on Telegram via BeautifulSoup. For example I want to take it from my channel post number 956: https://t.me/dayygesstt/956

```
<span class="tgme_widget_message_views">3.1K</span>
```

So "3.1K" is what I need.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url,'lxml')
    return r.text
url='https://t.me/dayygesstt/956'
html=get_html(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, )

x = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "tgme_page tgme_page_post"})

for i in x :
    r=i.findAll("div", {"class": "tgme_page_widget"})
    print(r)
```

and it prints:

```
[<div class="tgme_page_widget" id="widget">
<script async="" data-telegram-post="dayygesstt/956" data-width="100%" src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-
widget.js?4"></script>
</div>]
```

I tried different stuff but I can't get more info. Please help me, what am I doing wrong? How to get information properly?

Comment: It doesn't work because the content of that div element gets loaded dynamically with javascript.

Comment: thanks , what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the URL that loads the iframe in your script. Then you get just the widget without the cruft. For this take the original URL and append a query string "embed=1".

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://t.me/dayygesstt/956?embed=1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
views = soup.find("span", {"class": "tgme_widget_message_views"})
print(views.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define which parser to use with BeautifulSoup in order for it to parse the HTML correctly, so this line;

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, )
```

needs to be this;

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```